# Какой тег лучше использовать что бы добавить SVG изображение?

Tags: html, css, svg, изображения

**Object:**

```
 <object type="image/svg+xml" data="image.svg"></object>
```

**Embed:**

```
<embed type="image/svg+xml" src="image.svg" />
```

**iframe:**

```
<iframe src="image.svg"></iframe>
```

**IMG:**

```
<img src="image.svg" />
```

**background-image:**

```
#image {
  background-image: url(image.svg);
}
```

Comment: По стандартам тег <svg> является контейнером для масштабируемой векторной графики. Лучше придерживаться этого "правила".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучший тег для svg - это svg! Потому что только так вы в дальнейшем сможете им манипулировать. А вообще все зависит от целей, если просто показать картинку - img, если фоном пустить - то используйте background-image.

Answer (score 4):

Всё зависит от ваших потребностей, каждый метод дает определенные возможности и накладывает ограничения.

Если вам просто надо вставить готовую картинку, то стоит делать это так:

```
<img src="image.svg" alt="Image description" />
```

Соответственно, всё, что вы сможете - это менять ширину и высоту картинки, не более. Менять свойства элементов, анимировать их и всё прочее вы не сможете. А значит, никакого интерактива. Всё тоже самое справедливо и для вставки SVG как фонового изображения через CSS.

`<object>`, `<embed>` и `<iframe>` - это братья по разуму, в данном случае. Этим способом вы подключаете SVG как другую страницу, а значит требования по безопасности вставки растут, поскольку объект может содержать скрипты - с другого домена по-простому уже не вставить.

Ну и вы не упомянули еще один способ, а именно вставку векторной графики как тега `<svg />`. Когда вы вставляете SVG таким способом, у вас есть полный контроль над тем, что происходит внутри изображения, через CSS. Поменять цвет, повернуть, добавить анимацию, изменить размер при наведении и всё остальное, что только может прийти в голову. Но за это приходится платить - вы уже не сможете лениво подгрузить этот файл, браузер не сможет загрузить ресурс с более низким приоритетом, всё будет приходить прямо в теле ответа сервера и будет разбираться парсером браузера в первую очередь. Соответственно, кэшироваться ресурс тоже не будет.

Comment: отличный полный ответ, не понятно, почему его оценили недостаточно (+)